# Kivy - Error while trying to use my.kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I've just started learning kivy and I am unable to get a black window when I run this code, and this is an error:

> Kivy files require #:kivy !ex

This is my code snippet:

**gui_python.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label   
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MyGridLayout(Widget):


     name = ObjectProperty(None)
     userId = ObjectProperty(None)
   


     def press(self):
        name = self.name.text
        userId = self.id.text

        # print(f'hello {name} , your id {id}')
     #    self.add_widget(Label(text = f'name : {name} , id : {id}'))
        self.name.text = ""
        self.id.text = ""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    MyApp().run()
```

My **my.kv** file is:

```
<MyGridLayout>

    name:name
    userId:userId

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width , root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "user Name"
            TextInput:
                id :Name
                multiline:False    

            Label:
                text: "user id"
            TextInput:
                id:userId
                multiline:False 


        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.press()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **Builder.load_string()** and paste my .kv code in it and that's work

Answer (score 0):

gui_python.py

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label   
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MyGridLayout(Widget):
     name = ObjectProperty(None)
     userId = ObjectProperty(None)
     def press(self):
          name = self.name.text
          userId = self.userId.text # error fixed
          print(f'hello {name} , your id {userId}') # error fixed
          self.add_widget(Label(text = f'name : {name} , id : {userId}')) # error fixed
          self.name.text = ""
          self.userId.text = "" # error fixed

class My1App(App):
     def build(self):
          return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    My1App().run()
```

my.kv

---

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    name:name
    userId:userId
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width , root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: "user Name"
            TextInput:
                id :name # error fixed
                multiline:False
            Label:
                text: "user id"
            TextInput:
                id:userId
                multiline:False
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.press()
```

Comment: It still does not run and a black screen appears

Answer (score 0):

I just added the kivy version with `#:kivy 1.0.9`